# Finding a nice, secluded cabin in the U.S. wilderness

Tags: usa, outdoor-activities

What are some good resources to use in searching for a secluded cabin to rent in the U.S. wilderness?

Some places I've looked:

- [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org) occasionally references cabins.
- [Vacation Rentals by Owners](http://vrbo.com) (VRBO) is has a good interface to narrow down by characteristic.
- Some trail clubs have cabin listings. For example the [Potomac Area Trail Club](http://www.patc.net/PublicView/Cabins/PublicView/Custom/PATC_Cabins/Cabins.aspx).
- Many State web sites, like [Virginia's State Parks site](http://www.dcr.virginia.gov/state_parks/cabgen.shtml), list their cabins.
- Searching [TripAdvisor](http://tripadvisor.com) for cabin helps too, though I haven't found secluded wilderness cabins there yet.

Each of these is helpful in their own right. Are there other options? The more searchable (like VRBO and TripAdvisor) the better. The more secluded options listed (walk-in rather than drive-in, for example) the better. The more the resource describes the surrounding trails and scenery the better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. It sounds like you've found some through those sites? So are you just after more websites? That would fall into the 'asking for a list' or recommendation, which we try to avoid here.  Could you please clarify? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm hoping to find an easier way to look for secluded cabins. Unfortunately none of the options I've listed are easy and several may have nothing secluded at all. In other words, this almost seems like a word of mouth kind of endeavor, asking friends and friends of friends if they own or know of such cabins but I'm hoping there's a way to search online, for places that I would never hear about otherwise. That's what I'd like to find out from this community.

Comment: In Norway, I know from experience that there exist very secluded and nice free-to-use cabins. I think they are *on purpose* not advertised very well, because they could not be sustained as such if they were.

Comment: You might get better answers at [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @jlpp Do you care where they are?

Comment: Thanks gerrit. I'll check that site. @Karlson: I'm hoping to find a cabin in the north east U.S. but I wanted to make the question more general to help others who might have an interest in the same.

Comment: But please do not [cross-post](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3711/566)! I was just suggesting, you might want to ask on [both](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com) [metas](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com) to find where it fits better, then possibly migrate!

Answer (score 4):

There's [Flipkey](http://www.flipkey.com/) by Tripadvisor. It's pretty new so the listing are limited, but there's some pretty isolated and scenic places. Might want to try Craigslist too if you have a place in mind. Good luck!

Comment: I saw Flipkey when I was going through Tripadvisor, somehow. Maybe TripAdvisor is linking to their sister site. I'll give Craigslist a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no generic site to to look for this specific type of cabins but if you do a quick [Google for Wilderness Cabins](https://www.google.com/search?q=wilderness+cabins&aq=0&oq=wilderness+cab&aqs=chrome.1.57j0l3j62l2.7077&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) you can get a lot of options all over the US

- [Hawaii](http://www.nps.gov/hale/planyourvisit/wilderness-cabins.htm)
- [Alaska](http://goalaskan.com/)
- [More Alaska](http://www.kenaiwildernesscabins.com/cabins.html)
- [Michigan Upper Peninsula](http://www.sylvaniawildernesscabins.com/)
- [West Virginia](http://www.cassrailroad.com/wilderness_cabin.html)
- [Maine](http://www.flatironpondcabins.com/)
- [The Adirondacks](http://www.4peaks.com/fcamp.htm)

The list could go on and on but I think that would be enough for the moment given that it might be non-constructive as far as the [FAQ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) is concerned.

Comment: Thank you. My search began with Google, and with the right search terms it might be the best tool for this. I'll continue to experiment with the terms till I find more secluded places.